# How to overwrite previous routes in Angular so that it does not appear on clicking back button?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Please let me know your thoughts on the following. Any help is appreciated as I am really new to Angular.

**Scenario** : My application has a payment page that redirects to an external payment gateway. This payment gateway returns a session token that is appended with my application URL that needs to be processed just once to authorize the payment and store the payment in db via API. So now, I have 2 URLs (external gateway url and the application url with the appended session) that should not be included in my previous routes. How can I achieve the same in a way that I can avoid being redirected to these two URLs when I click the back button? Is there any way to remove the last two routes from the route history?

ie, suppose I am initially on **http://localhost:4200/view-test?type=newtype&id=123**. Once I click payment button, it redirects to 2 other URLs. Those URLs should be changed accordingly but when I click back once the process is over, it should take me to the URL before the above mentioned one.

Thanks in advance for your time. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below :-

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

or be on current url while still navigating like :-

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```